# Методе name() в Enum и нужен ли он вообще?

Tags: java

```
public enum Colors {
    BLACK, WHITE, RED, BLUE, GREEN
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Colors color1 = Colors.RED;
        System.out.println(color1);
        System.out.println(color1.name());
    }
}
```

Зачем вообще тогда нам нужен name(), если и без него выдает тоже самый результат в консоли.

Answer (score 3):

Внутри `println` у объектов неявно вызывается `toString()`.

По умолчанию `toString()` и `name()` у `enum` возвращают одну и ту же строку, поэтому у вас результат одинаковый.

Но `toString()` вы можете переопределить как хотите, а `name()` нет, так как он `final` в абстрактном классе `java.lang.Enum`, от которого наследуются `enum`-ы.

```
public enum Colors {
    BLACK, WHITE, RED, BLUE, GREEN;

    // Нельзя:
    //@Override
    //public String name() {
    //  return "my string";
    //}

    // Можно:
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "my string";
    }
}
```